# I'm trying to develop code in Laravel to copy a work item to another PBI, using the Azure DevOps API with PHP and Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, azure, api

I'm trying to make a copy of work items (Tasks, etc.) from one location to another in Azure DevOps, using PHP and Laravel. I was able to send data in JSON format to the Azure API and create a task (according to the example posted). I can't make a copy. Can you help me?

```php
Route::get('/add_work_item', function () {
    $response = Http::withBasicAuth('{key}', '{PAT}')
        ->withHeaders([
            'Content-Type' => 'application/json-patch+json'
        ])
        ->post('https://dev.azure.com/{Organisation}/{Project}/_apis/wit/workitems/$Task?api-version=5.1', [
            [
                'op' => 'add',
                'path' => '/fields/System.Title',
                'from' => null,
                'value' => 'New Task'
            ],
            [
                'op' => 'add',
                'path' => '/fields/System.AreaPath', 'from' => null, 'value' => '{Project}'
            ]
        ]);

    return dd(json_decode($response->getBody()));
});
```

Comment: `dd` means die and dump, you don't return it, it just runs and kill the page

Comment: Thanks salim for the help in formatting the code. I am new to this group. I'm learning about the forum tools.

Comment: In that case I used dd just to stop the program and show the result. I still haven't been able to find a feature in the Azure API that allows copying work items.